# add new div with effect jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this page: [image]

As you can see, I have a button with "crear orden" legend. How can I do this:
[image]

I have the same model, and I don't know how can do this effect.

Comment: Holy geeze.  This animation is complex enough that *I'd* have trouble replicating it even if I was being *paid.*

Comment: That's smooth, did you make it in Photoshop?

Comment: the company where i work give me this example i just only try do this

Comment: Can you share what code you currently have?

Comment: sorry but i don't have any code, only found the way to put down a div, but clicking in the button, nothing!!

Answer (score 0):

Steps of this animation, all can be done with jQuery/CSS:
-clear content inside
-position element absolute in both center and middle (tricky!)
-animate height and width to 0
-"slideDown" hidden/added element on list

As You haven't posted any code- neither do I.